# How to extend ubuntu partition?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I attempted to extend my ubuntu partition using windows disk management, but quickly realized that you cannot extend a volume with this file system using that method. [Here is an image of what disk management shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wwmb.png)

I want to be able to extend my ubuntu partition to use the unallocated space.

Answer (score 0):

First, backup all your data on both the Windows and Ubuntu partitions.
Second, install `gparted` if you don't have it installed already. Third, use `gparted` to resize your Ubuntu partition.

`gparted` is a powerful program. You can delete partitions, resize partitions, reformat partitions, and wipe your data beyond all hope of recovery.